# How to use resources in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

I write C# Windows form in Visual Studio.

In code of application I load image from local maschin using absolute path:

```
string path = "C:\imag.png"
```

Ater I load this in pictureBox.

Problem is that when I compile program and run on another computer I get errors, because there are not files, that should be loaded.

How can I use resources in VS or compress images in exe file?